# Is there a way to set Keyboard.FocusedElement to a specific element?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, focus

Keyboard.FocusedElement gives the element that has keyboard focus. However it has no setter. I want to set this property to another element through code. is there a way?

On [microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.focusedelement.aspx), it said this: "Keyboard focus refers to the object that is receiving keyboard input. The element with keyboard focus has IsKeyboardFocused set to true."

However IsKeyboardFocused also has no setter as well.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just looking for the `UIElement.Focus()` method.

Comment: Wow I think I over-thought this. Thanks a lot.